# Auto-resizable box

Tags: boxes

How to create a box like `parbox` which automatically resizes to the length of its content and can contain multiple lines?
I tried `mbox` but it can contain one line of text only; on the other hand, `parbox` requires a fixed width.

Comment: `varwidth` environment from package of the same name.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I added a link to an already answered question that should help you, together with the comment by David.